# Typeroots option in tsconfig.json does not recognize custom types

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a typescript project set up to work with ./node_modules/types, here is my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "mapRoot": "./",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types",
            "./types"
        ]
    }
}
```

However if I move one of the folders from ./node_modules/@types to ./types the corresponding types aren't picked up by typescript, what can be the reason for such problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A poor workaround is installing your declarations in `node_modules/@types/` or maybe even symlinking that to `types/`.